# Unable to see a console log in a LWC method which is being called from an Aura component

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I have a simple Aura Component that has a LWC component inside it like this:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    
    <c:taxCalculator aura:id="taxCalculator" name="xxx" />    

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>    

</aura:component>
```

The aura controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('taxCalculator').computeTax();
        console.log('FINISHED');
    }
})
```

The lwc:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class TaxCalculator extends LightningElement {
  @api name;

  @api
  computeTax() {    
    console.log('HERE');

  }
  
}
```

metadata of the lwc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

In the console log of the browser I see `FINISHED`, but not `HERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces the following warning in Chrome:

> WARNING: Methods are not available until the component is rendered

> logWarning@aura_proddebug.js51519

You have to wait until rendering is complete.

Try:

```
({
  doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    setTimeout(
      $A.getCallback(() => component.find("taxCalculator").computeTax())
    );
    console.log("FINISHED");
  },
});
```

Note that the output will be:

```
 FINISHED
 HERE
```

Because it is an asynchronous call.

Comment: as always you are a savior. Thank you. But reagarding the warning message you saw in chrome, I didn't see any. Was there a option you activated, to see?

Comment: @nSv23 Not that I know of. I just happened to open the console (F12) and saw it.